# Reuse function output multiple times in excel formula

Tags: excel, formula

I would like to use an excel formula like `=IF(ISERROR(<MyBigFunction>), "ERROR", <MyBigFunction>)`
Is there a way to avoid entering twice my big formula, without storing it in another cell ?

Something like `=IF(ISERROR(variable=<MyBigFunction>), "ERROR", variable)`

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`IFERROR`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611):

```
=IFERROR(<MyBigFunction>, "ERROR")
```